# function not executing on different view

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-scope

I am new to **angular JS**. I have created a simple page using **ngRoute**.
In the first view I have a table, and on clicking it redirects to second view.
But I have called two functions using `ng-click` the `changeView` functions is running fine. But the second function  fails to execute on the second view.
But Its running fine if using on the first view itself.
Heres the code for first view
**Angular.php**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dataCtr">
<table class='table table-striped'>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Stream</td>
<td>Price</td>
</tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody> 
 <tr ng-repeat = "x in names | filter:filtr | filter:search"  ng-click="  disp(x.id);changeView()">

 <td >{{ x.Title }}</td>
 <td>{{ x.Stream }}</td>
 <td>{{ x.Price }}</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

heres the second View
**details.php**:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dataCtr"> 
 <div class="container">
 SELECTED:<input type="textfield" ng-model="stxt">
</div>
</div>
```

heres the **js file**:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/angular', {
        templateUrl: 'angular.php',
        controller: 'dataCtr'
    })
    .when('/details', {
        templateUrl: 'details.php',
        controller: 'dataCtr'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/angular'
    });
});
 app.controller('dataCtr', function($scope ,$http ,$location ,$route ,$routeParams) {
$http({
 method: "GET",
 url: "json.php"})
.success(function (response) {$scope.names = response;});     
$scope.changeView = function()
{
  $location.url('/details');
};

$scope.disp = function(id)
{
  $scope.stxt = $scope.names[id-1].Title;
};
});
```

The `disp` function is working fine on the angular view. But not being routed on the second view. I think the syntax for calling the two views in ng click is correct. OR if there any other method to call the associated table cell value to the second view. Please Help.

Comment: you should have a different controller for each view

Comment: Using the same controller name in both views does not mean view is shared. Each time a view is loaded a new controller is created. Also why does both of your view have `ng-app` declaration

Comment: ok about the ng-app declaration, i thought it was necessary(New to angular:) ).And about using the same controller ,I thought different views of a single site work this way.But using two controllers also doesnt work .

Comment: to share data among different controllers, use have to use service and for data persistence use local storage.

Comment: @DanishAltafSatti , i worked on your advice,Using a factory service worked.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lots of research i figured it out.I used a factory service

```
app.factory('Scopes', function ($rootScope) {
var mem = {};
return {
    store: function (key, value) {
        $rootScope.$emit('scope.stored', key);
        mem[key] = value;
    },
    get: function (key) {
        return mem[key];
    }
};
});
```

Added this to JS.
Because The scope gets lost on second Controller ,Services help us retain the scope value and use them in different controllers.Stored the scope  from first controller

```
app.controller('dataCtr', function($scope ,$http ,$location,$rootScope,Scopes) {
Scopes.store('dataCtr', $scope); 
//code
});
```

and loaded in the seconded controller.

```
app.controller('dataCtr2', function($scope ,$timeout,$rootScope,Scopes){
$scope.stxt = Scopes.get('dataCtr').disp;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Second view is not working because you cannot use $scope.$apply() method.
$apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework.$scope.$apply() right after you have changed the location Angular know that things have changed.

change following code part ,try again

```
$location.path('/detail');
 $scope.$apply();
```

Comment: You mean i should call the disp() function in My changeView Function,after calling the URL

Comment: yes, so $location.url replace with $location.path then add $scope.$apply

Comment: i tried location.path but thats not working...its not redirecting to another view...And should i use a different controller for second view.?